# How to recieve Apple Push notification payload when User responds to Notification on watch

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, watch, payload

my app registers at the appDelegate for recieveing remote push notifications.

As long as there is no Apple Watch connected to the phone, the notification is displayed at the iphone and as soon as the user taps the message the app starts and handles the push notification payload.

BUT if the user has an apple watch connected to the iphone and responds to the notification at his watch, the payload is lost (the delegate is not called at the iOS app and the message disappears at the iphone screen).

I could not find any documentation explaining how this was designed by apple and how this situation could be solved.

The goal is, that the iOS app always recieves the apple push notification payload.

Whats the correct way to solve this?

Comment: The app will always receive your payload. Watch is a "client". Watch can answer the notification only if you have developed a notification handler. If not, it will only shows the push content message. In others words, if you do nothing, your app will work. But forcibly, if the user dismiss the notification on the watch, it will be dismissed on the phone

Comment: If the user dismisses the notification at the watch, the delegate at the app is not called and so the payload ist lost. This means i have to develop an extension for the watch to make sure that the payload is handed over somehow by the watch to the app in case the user dismisses the notification at the watch?